# Odd error (UITextSelectionView) while calling a method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods, runtime-error

I'm facing a problem while calling a method and I don't know how figure it out.
Basically, during the main menu, I want to call a SKNode showing a tutorial part. The code is the following:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    ...

    if ([[GameData sharedData] openingTutorial]) { // Checks if the menu needs the tutorial
        [_tutorialObj performSelector:@selector(runTutorialWithStep:)
                           withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8]
                           afterDelay:3.0
         ];
    }
}
```

When the method `didMoveToView:` is called (even before waiting the 3 seconds for the `runTutorialWithStep:`), I got this error:

`[UITextSelectionView name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1576e6c0
2014-10-14 11:01:19.430 
[406:130379] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextSelectionView name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1576e6c0'`

The odd thing is that in the previous class I use the same tutorial's action in the `didMoveToView:` and it's working right. But...

Thing is getting more strange here!!!

If I use an intermediary method for this calls:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    ...

    [self performSelector:@selector(intermediaryMethod)
              withObject:nil
              afterDelay:3.0
     ];
}

- (void)intermediaryMethod
{
    [_tutorialObj performSelector:@selector(runTutorialWithStep:)
                       withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8]
                       afterDelay:0.0
     ];
}
```

Everything works without issues. I don't want to avoid the problem but solve this. Any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem.

I added a breakpoint for every exception and I realized that the issues was due to an other class (the only one with UITextView).
Basically I removed the text field from its parent (`[self removeFromParent]`) by my own once I did not need it anymore.

I suppose the error was fired during the deallocation 'cause the program can't find the UITextView. I managed to remove this statement and everything works right.

Actually I still have doubts because I don't understand why this exception is throw only if I call the `[_tutorialObj runTutorialWithStep:]` method.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. You try to send a 'name' message to object that doesn't implement it (UITextSelectionView). Since your second take works the cause is either in

```
[[GameData sharedData] openingTutorial]
```

method or before this call. Search for objects calling 'name' and check if it's the UITextSelectionView in question.

That or maybe you have weak reference to general view object and during those three seconds before calling runTutorialWithStep you reassign it to object that implements 'name' message.

Comment: I tried to test the code part you told me to check but the problem is not there. If I try: `if ([[GameData sharedData] openingTutorial]) NSLog(@"DEBUG");` every works! Anyways, In this method I did not even use UITextSelectionView!

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to fix it.

```
UITextView *textView = .....

textView.selectable = NO;
```